# Выбор багтрекера

Tags: bug-tracking

Что хотелось бы:

1. Локальный, то есть всякие публичные
       на чужих хостингах отпадают (но с доступом по HTTP, конечно)
2. (Не обязательно, но желательно) интеграция с dokuwiki (бывают
       встроенные wiki-движки, но
       полноценная dokuwiki лучше, и она должна работать автономно)
3. Простой во всех смыслах
4. Perl (предпочтительней) или PHP.
       Если захочется что-то дописать, то
       на RoR или питоне мне будет сложней
       это сделать (4a: не на каждом виртуальном хостинге есть Ruby или питон, а надо бы иметь возможность ставить. Java вообще не рассматривается)
5. Из 4 следует - расширяемый (плагины
       etc)
6. Бесплатный.

Пока смотрел:

1. Bugzilla. Не люблю её почему-то,
       просто не люблю :) Но если расскажете про плюсы - хорошо :)
2. Mantis. С ним работал много, хорошо
       знаю потроха. Из минусов - кошмарная
       локализация (мне-то и английский
       нормально, но...), да и монструозен
       он слишком для моих целей.
3. [Traq](http://traq.io/). Почти то что надо:
       простой как 5 копеек и шустрый. Из
       минусов - текущая версия не очень
       кастомизуется. Например, только с
       помощью танцев с бубном можно
       выкинуть roadmap и timeline, которые
       совсем не нужны.
4. [Eventum](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/other/eventum/) Последняя версия
       выпущена в 2009 году...
5. [The Bug Genie](http://thebuggenie.com/) Слишком
       монстрообразен :)

Что ещё посмотреть?

Comment: `Jira / Youtrack`?

Comment: Забыл добавить - бесплатный :) А YouTrack на Java :(

Comment: Есть еще Redmine, но я его не могу читать, весь текст сливается, часто не вижу важных моментов в документации.
Но это у меня на работе, может можно просто дизайн другой натянуть.

Comment: Про него слышал много хорошего, но - ruby... Сейчас добавлю ещё почему Perl/PHP, пункт 4a :)

Comment: @nMike - Redmine еще та хрень, у меня тоже на прошлой работе с ним проблемы постоянные были.
Я за Jira и Youtrack ))

Comment: Я даже готов поднять томкат, или рельсы проложить :) Но при одном условии: вся ненужная хрень должна отключаться. Для больших и серьёзных проектов - да, это важно. Но не всегда нужен велосипед с тышей скоростей и понтовыми грипсами :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org/) - простенько и со вкусом! (от создателя SQLite)

Comment: Спасибо, гляну. (прямо аж фидошностью от названия повеяло :)

Answer (score 2):

> Mantis. С ним работал много, хорошо
> знаю потроха. Из минусов - кошмарная
> локализация (мне-то и английский
> нормально, но...), да и монструозен он
> слишком для моих целей.

Мне тут как раз он на глаза попался, и кстати, да с локалями плоховато, но всегда можно подправить.

В остальном меня устроил!

еще интересный это Fossil о нем писали выше.

Answer (score 1):

http://bitbucket.org/

Comment: Не вижу кнопочки "download".

Comment: он не локальный )

Answer (score 0):

А почему не [RT](https://rt.perl.org/rt3/)?

Comment: Давно смотрел, кажется, там были какие-то проблемы с установкой на виртуальном хостинге.